# Flex still includes FlexLexer.h with options noyywrap and nounistd

Tags: c++, visual-c++, flex-lexer

Flex still includes the FlexLexer.h even when using the noyywrap and nounistd option. I don't know why.
I'm using the Linux subshell on Windows to generate with flex thus I don't have this header available.

Our build process is based on CMake and I don't want to have another dependency in form of the FlexLexer header. Weirdly yesterday I got it working but I somehow changed something and I can't figure out what it is or why it won't work.

Flex source:

```
%option noyywrap nounistd c++ never-interactive outfile="Tokenizer.cpp"

%{
    int a = 0;
%} 

%%
"\n" {a++;}
%%
```

I mean it's not usefull but it also generates the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FlexLexer.h` is part of Flex's C++ API; it cannot be suppressed if you want to generate an OO scanner, because  it defines the scanner's base class. If you be are accidentally using the C++ interface, that header will be the least of your problems. But there is no need; in default C mode, flex produces a scanner which can be compiled with C++. If you really need the C++ API, which is not the same as needing a scanner for a C++ environment, then you will need that file, and you will find it in the flex installation, even on Windows.

None of this has anything to do with `yywrap`. You're probably thinking of the dependency on `libfl`, which becomes unnecessary if you use `%option noyywrap`. (If you require the `yywrap` feature, `libfl` won't help you; it just provides a default implementation of `yywrap` which effectively disables the feature.)

Answer (score 0):

Generated code **always** adds the line

```
#include <FlexLexer.h>
```

So the file `FlexLexer.h` must be available somewhere in your CMake include directories. Usually you can find it in `/usr/shared`.

Since you are using c++ you can take a look at [flexcpp](https://github.com/fbb-git/flexcpp), which do not require additional include files and could be easily automated with CMake.

Comment: Yeah sure but from what I witnessed when using `noyywrap` this include won't be put inside the cpp and all references to the fl lib will be removed.
But I figured it out myself, the c++ option also uses the FlexLexer.h by removing it the dependency is gone.

Comment: I think `noyywrap` is for different thing. Flex always includes `FlexLexer.h`.